# Printing to a network thermal printer

Tags: php, printing, xampp

I am designing a restaurant POS system for my self and I am facing a little problem.
My webserver is XAMPP on Windows 7 32 bit having IP 192.168.1.20. There is a network thermal printer connected directly to the network on IP 192.168.1.25. I installed this printer on the webserver and it is working perfectly from windows environment. I also shared this printer on the webserver with name "P2"

Now I have mapped this network printer to LPT1 by using the command:

NET USE LPT1: \192.168.1.20\P2 /PERSISTENT:Yes

Now the problem is:
when I print a file from the command prompt using command

print file1.txt /d:LPT1
this works like a charm, but when I call this command from my php webpage using command

exec('print file1.txt /d:LPT1');
nothing happens...

When I tried to debug the issue using

exec('print file1.txt /d:LPT1', $output);
var_dump($output);

the following error comes:

array(1) { [0]=> string(32) "Unable to initialize device LPT1" }

Now I really don't know, what's wrong with this.

Help needed

Comment: Great question. I don't think it belongs in programming site. Maybe in http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: From the network engineering point of view, everything is working fine when i send a file from command prompt. But when I execute the same command in php using exec() function, nothing happens